# Why I'm getting just data's first letters when I'm writing array?

Tags: php, arrays

I've an array `$new_data`, and result of `print_r($new_data['comments']);` is as follows

```
Array (
    [id] => 1 
    [uye] => yusufalibozkir 
    [yorum] => Saffet gel beni affet 
    [post] => 1 
)
```

But when I want to print my datas with using foreach loop:

```
foreach($new_data['comments'] as $comments)
{
    echo $comments['id'];
}
```

The result:

```
1yS1
```

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:

This question might be like below
I'm creating array like below:

```
$comments = $this->post_model->getComments($data['id']);
            foreach($comments as $comments)
            {
                $comments['uye'] = $this->members_model->lognick($comments['uye']);
            }
```

Actually, It need to have 2 array inside of main array. Because my table has 2 rows. But It returns just last data.

Comment: The problem is lack of understanding of arrays. Just for practice, try the following: `foreach($new_data['comments'] as $key => $value) { echo "$key = $value"; }` and see the difference.

Comment: Perhaps you're expecting to get a complete "comments" array in `$comments` inside your `foreach` loop. But actually what you get inside you loop is, `1`, `yusufalibozkir`, `Saffet gel beni affet`, and `1` **strings/ints**. When you use `$comments['id']` on these strings, PHP treats them as array and prints only first character, an you get `1yS1`

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to get in your output based on that array?

Comment: @Ejay yes I can't add datas into array as I want. It just return last row.

Comment: @smerny 2 array inside of array because I have 2 rows in database.

Comment: @user2328931, what are you hoping to have as the output (what all gets echoed) based on the array?

Comment: 2 line, first line id 1, seconds line id 2

Comment: @user2328931 Where would the 2 be coming from? The array doesn't contain a 2. Please show your real data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$comments = $this->post_model->getComments($data['id']);
foreach($comments as $comments)
{
    $comments['uye'] = $this->members_model->lognick($comments['uye']);
}
```

This code is an example of unexpected behavior of PHP. Notice `foreach($comments as $comments)` both sides of `as` are same variable so eventually your original `$comments` variable is overwritten by last value of `$comments` inside `foreach` and is reduced to *value array* of the comment instead of being an array of comments, and you get

```
Array (
    [id] => 1 
    [uye] => yusufalibozkir 
    [yorum] => Saffet gel beni affet 
    [post] => 1 
)
```

instead of an array containing such arrays.

Fix it like follows

```
$comments = $this->post_model->getComments($data['id']);
foreach($comments as $key => $comm)
{
    $comments[$key]['uye'] = $this->members_model->lognick($comm['uye']);
}
```

and your original code should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is when you do a foreach it is actually returning each object in the array, so when you are putting the index in, it's an index for the string... just remove the index in your echo

```
echo $comments;
```

Comment: replace your echo with the one above... let us know if that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<?php 

$new_data['comments'] =array('id' => 1 ,'uye' => 'yusufalibozkir', 'yorum' => 'Saffet gel beni affet','post' => 1);
foreach($new_data['comments'] as $comments)
            {
                echo $comments."<br/>";
            }
?>

//output: 1
          yusufalibozkir
          Saffet gel beni 
          affet
          1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
foreach($new_data['comments'] as $comments)
{
    echo $comments."<br>"; //replace with $comments['id'];
}
```

**Output**

```
1
yusufalibozkir
Saffet gel beni 
affet
1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Strings, you have to use `""`.
For example:

```
[yorum] => "Saffet gel beni affet",
```

If you make an array, you have to use `,` to separate the elements.

Comment: @Hydroid the array in the question is result of a `print_r()` so it does not contain strings quoted with "" and comma after each index